# Is it possible to register a helper for a single handlebars template?

Tags: handlebars.js

I would like to create a handlebars template and use a local helper for just that single template.  I know how to use Handlebars.registerHelper to register helpers for all templates, but I only need this for the local template.  (something similar to what ExtJS supports with XTemplates)

For example something like this based upon handlebars.js documentation:

```
var context = { posts: [{url: "/hello-world", body: "Hello World!"}] };
var source = "<ul>{{#posts}}<li>{{{link_to this}}}</li>{{/posts}}</ul>"

var template = Handlebars.compile(source, {
   link_to: function(context) {
       return "<a href='" + context.url + "'>" + context.body + "</a>";
   }
);
template(context);
```

Is this possible or do all helpers have to be registered globally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
template(context, {helpers: helpers})
```

Local helpers redefine global. So if you want `each`, `if` or other registered global helpers just extend object:

```
helpers = $.extend({}, Handlebars.helpers, helpers);
template(context, {helpers: helpers})
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI, extending `Handlebars.helpers` isn't necessary. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cdN7/).

Comment: at that time it was :)